# How to navigate a webpage using keyboard inputs with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently in the middle of a web scraping project. In order to fine tune the content I have to interact with different elements of a web page, specifically a drag and drop cursor. I have tried the drag and drop method within selenium but for some reason the element cannot be selected, be it with xpath or classname. I can, however, select the element above it. I want to navigate to the cursor by "pressing" tab 3 times and then bring it to the left by "pressing" left arrow 5 times. I have tried doing so with the following lines of code:

`actions = ActionChains(driver)`

`actions.click(criteres).send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT * 5).perform()`

But it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver) 
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3)
actions.perform()
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT * 5)
actions.perform()
```